# Php Query regarding URL setting in CURL

Tags: php, openshift, openshift-origin

I am new to PHP, just started exploring it a few hours ago.

I am working in Openshift and have deployed a CustomerApp Pod which has a Service name `customer` and port `8080`.

I deployed another simple PHP app in the same project/namespace which has `index.php` with below content. When I try to call Route of my PHP app, it gives an 503 error.

I guess `http://customer:8080` is being taken as a string and not an URL. What should I add to tell PHP that it should be considered as an URL?

```
<?php 
$url="http://customer:8080";

$client=curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($client,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$response=curl_exec($client);

echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: URLs are strings, there's no coercion needed. I'd start by calling `curl_getinfo()` after your `curl_exec()` and dumping the result. That will show you details about the connection.

Comment: Basically I agree with Alex. You are initializing curl correctly but the execution probably fails. This is not answerable without more info, you have to learn how to debug in PHP. Use `var_dump($result)` and if the result use `echo curl_error()`. Update your question with the debug info (http://php.net/manual/de/function.curl-error.php).

Answer (score -2):

The `curl_init()` call doesn't take an arg -

```
$url = "https://api.example.com:8000/get/some/info";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I am a newbie in PHP, but I guess it does take an arg, because when I used other REST services, it did provide a valid response as echo. The thing with Openshift is we just mention the name of http://Service:Port